# I can't see the Config directory in Developer view in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

When I created a new content page, the link to document was showing blank after publishing, I think I need to look into:

```
<add key="umbracoUseDirectoryUrls" value="false" />

<add key="umbracoUseDirectoryUrls" value="true" />
```

and see if it works. However I can't find the Config folder in Developer view even though I have admin access.

Any idea please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to access config files via the Umbraco backend, you'll need to install the [Config Tree](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/config-tree) package. Then and only then will the Config tree/folder appear in the Developer section.

Otherwise you will have to make edits to the web.config and other config files from the local file system.